# Could someone help clarify an example in my linear algebra book on orthonormal bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

*Linear Algebra with Applications* by Steven J. Leon, p.257:

> **Theorem 5.5.2:** Let $\{\textbf{u}_1, \textbf{u}_2, \ldots, \textbf{u}_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for an inner product space $V$.  If $\textbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \textbf{u}_i$, then $c_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$.

I don't know if I need to include the proof, but it's short, so here it is:

> **Definition:** $\delta_{ij} = 
> \begin{cases}
>  1 & \text{if } i = j \\
>  0 & \text{if } i \neq j
> \end{cases}$
>
> **Proof:** $$\langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle = \left< \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j \textbf{u}_j, \textbf{u}_i \right> = \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j \langle \textbf{u}_j, \textbf{u}_i \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j \delta_{ij} = c_i$$

Now here's the example given in the book.  He seems to be using the theorem's logic backwards.  I don't get it.

> **Example:** The vectors
>   $$ \textbf{u}_1 = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^T \text{  and  } \textbf{u}_2 = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^T$$
>   form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then
>   $$\textbf{x}^T \textbf{u}_1 = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \text{  and  } \textbf{x}^T \textbf{u}_2 = \dfrac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
>   It follows from Theorem 5.5.2 that
>   $$\textbf{x} = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{u}_1 + \dfrac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{u}_2$$

Isn't "$\textbf{x} = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{u}_1 + \dfrac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \textbf{u}_2$" referring to "$\textbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \textbf{u}_i$", and "$\textbf{x}^T \textbf{u}_1 = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt{2}} \text{  and  } \textbf{x}^T \textbf{u}_2 = \dfrac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}}$" referring to "$c_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$"?  Shouldn't the latter follow from the former?  Or should the theorem state if and only if?  Or am I just confused?

Comment: There is nothing strictly wrong with what he wrote; but, perhaps, it would be more clear if he instead wrote "If ${\bf x}=c_1{\bf u}_1+c_2{\bf u}_2\in\Bbb R^2$, then $$c_1={\bf x}^T{\bf u}_1 ={x_1+x_2\over\sqrt2}\ \text{and} \ c_2={\bf x}^T{\bf u}_2\ ...$$

Comment: Well, if you have a theorem that says that A implies B, you can't use that theorem and B to conclude A.  That's what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* vector in your inner product space can be expressed as a unique linear combination of your basis elements.

Just think about it, when would $\langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$ ever not equal the $i'$th coefficient?

That's why the converse is true.

Comment: I can see how $\langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$ would never not equal the $i$'th coefficient if $\textbf{u}_i$ were equal to the standard basis element $\textbf{e}_i$ because it would just be filtering out the $i$'th component of the vector.

Comment: I think I'm too tired and burned out to think about this properly.  Why does this happen? :-P

Comment: Not that's not right.  I'm unchecking your thing :-P  What needs to be proven is that if $c_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$, then $\textbf{v} = \sum_{j=1}^n c_i \textbf{u}_i$.

Comment: That follows by the fact that every $v \in V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of your basis elements.

Comment: Take $\textbf{v} \in V $ and suppose $c_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$.  Since $\{\textbf{u}_1,...,\textbf{u}_n\}$ is a basis for our inner product space, there exists scalars $b_1,...,b_n$ such that $\textbf{v}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i \textbf{u}_i$.  Hence  $b_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle = c_i$.

Comment: And you get from $\textbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \textbf{u}_i$ to $b_i = \langle \textbf{v}, \textbf{u}_i \rangle$ by the theorem!  Okay, I think I get it now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We know that $x = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2$ for some $c_1, c_2$.

By the theorem, $c_1 = \left< x, u_1 \right>$ and $c_2 = \left< x, u_2 \right>$.

Thus $$x = \left< x, u_1 \right> u_1 + \left< x, u_2 \right> u_2 = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt{2}} u_1 + \frac{x_1 - x_2}{\sqrt{2}} u_2$$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, any $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination
$$\mathbf{x} = a_1 \mathbf{u}_1 + a_2 \mathbf{u}_2. \tag{$\ast$}$$
Taking the inner product of $(\ast)$ with $\mathbf{u}_1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle & = \langle a_1 \mathbf{u}_1 + a_2 \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle \\
 & = \langle a_1 \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle + \langle a_2 \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle \\
 & = a_1 \langle \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle + a_2 \langle \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle \\
 & = a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot 0 \\
 & = a_1.
\end{align*}
A similar calculation shows that
$$\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u}_2 \rangle = a_2.$$
Therefore
$$a_1 = \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u}_1 \rangle = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{u}_1,$$
$$a_2 = \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{u}_2 \rangle = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{u}_2.$$

This process can be used to show that the converse of the theorem is true.

Comment: @MattGregory: I've edited my answer to address your clarifications in the comments. Let me know if this clears up your confusion.

Comment: Yeah, that did help.  Thank you!